# filter the text file using multiple regex in ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I have the text file contains the below text which I need to filter based on condition.

```
CODE=0xea00e60c  
CODE=0xea00e60d  
OUTPUT="HW Address: 91183010\n,HWType:00000030\n"  
CODE=0xea00e60e  
CODE=0xea01ff00
```

If the line starts with CODE, extract everything after 0x(e.g ea00e60c) from 1st line and paste in **xyz** file.
If the line starts with OUTPUT, extract out everything under double quotes and paste in **xyz** files. Sequence of extracting and putting the text in **XYZ** file should be maintained.

```
  def filter_logs(filename)
    postcode = "postcode_logs"
    File.open(filename, 'r').each do |line|
      result = (line.scan(/"(.*?)"/)) || (line.split("x")[1])
      File.open(postcode, 'a') do |selected_line|
        selected_line.puts(result)
      end
    end
  end
```

filename and postcode is file defined already.

There is no error in code but output is also not there.

```
**Expected output**

  ea00e60c  
  ea00e60d  
  HW Address: 91183010\n,HWType:00000030\n  
  ea00e60e  
  ea01ff00



**current output**
HW Address: 91183010\n,HWType:00000030\n
```

Comment: `String#scan` will never return a falsey value, so your other clause is ignored. Check for empty array explicitly or use something other than `scan`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  What can be the possible solution, should I go with with if-else ?

Comment: You can reverse the clauses, for example. The other one _does_ return nil.

Comment: the variable `selected_line` is actually a file, which is opened and closed for every line in `filename`. This is costly.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev, your suggestion worked, I just need to reverse the clause and it works !!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't succeed is because [`#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-scan) always succeeds. If nothing is found an empty array is returned (which evaluates as truthy). Simply getting the first result should be good enough (returning `nil` for empty arrays):

```
result = line.scan(/"(.*?)"/).first || line.split("x")[1]
```

Although you could also use other techniques like:

```
result   = line[/\ACODE=0x(\h*)/, 1]
result ||= line[/\AOUTPUT="([^"]*)"/, 1]
```

Matching from the start of the string either `CODE=0x` followed by zero or more hexadecimal characters (`\h*`) capturing them in group 1 or `OUTPUT="` followed by zero or more non-quote characters (`[^"]*`) capturing them in group 1 followed by a `"`.

Check out the [regular expression documentation for Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/regexp_rdoc.html) if anything is unclear about the regex. Check out the [documentation of the square bracket accessor of String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) if anything is unclear about the square bracket method usage.

Comment: It doesn't give any output, I ran, result = line[/\A(?:CODE=0x(\h*)|OUTPUT="([^"]*))"/, 1]

Comment: I had placed the last quote outside the group. I've updated the regex. Check the edit to if you're curious to what exactly changed.

Comment: I've also noticed that the output for `OUTPUT=""` doesn't match, since it's captured in group 2 instead. So I've split it into 2 different regexes.